# How to display one value if value have more than one value that same inside foreach?

Tags: php

How to display one value if value have more than one value that same inside foreach ?

```
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

In array colors value **red** and **blue** more than one value, so I whant to show just one value. **red, green, blue, and yellow**

Comment: use `array_unique`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)

> array_unique — Removes duplicate values from an array

```
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 
$colors = array_unique($colors);
foreach ($colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/932025

***Note:- If you don't want to change initial array then use `array_unique()` inside `foreach()`***

```
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach (array_unique($colors) as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/932027

***Or you can create a new variable also:-***

```
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 
$unique_colors = array_unique($colors);
foreach ($unique_colors as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/932028

Comment: @silviazulinka  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 2):

The **[array_unique()](https://www.w3resource.com/php/function-reference/array_unique.php)** is used to remove duplicate values from an array.

```
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 

foreach (array_unique($colors) as $value) {
    echo "$value <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) function like below.

Try this:

```
<?php 
$colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 
$colors = array_unique($colors);
print_r($colors);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `array_unique($arrayName)` to get unique (distinct) values from array.

```
<?php 
   $colors = array("red", "red", "green", "blue", "blue", "yellow"); 
   foreach (array_unique($colors) as $value) {
       echo "$value <br>";
    }
?>
```